# Xamarin Android Local Notifications App not running

Tags: android, xamarin, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Local notification not working when app is not running (ie not in Foreground / Background)

My application will create a bunch of "reminders".  For simplicity, each reminder is scheduled for a specific time every day.

This is Xamarin Android (NOT FORMS).

If the app is in the foreground, I just show an alert.  (WORKS)
If the app is in the background, I generate a local notification. (WORKS)

In the app is closed (ie, not running, swiped away!) I do not receive the "reminders".  (NOT WORKING)
If the device is rebooted, I want the reminders to still arrive even if the app has not been run yet.

I have read some posts that say to edit the manifest, but that did not help
I have read some posts that suggest using a Service, but I can't figure out how to schedule / reschedule the "reminders".

App Flow.
From the UI, when the reminders are saved.

```
Intent intent101 = new Intent(MainActivity.getInstance(), typeof(NotifcationReceiver));
intent101.SetAction($"{_notifcationCount}");

PendingIntent op101 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.getInstance(), intent101, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.getInstance().GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService);
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, time101, AlarmManager.IntervalDay, op101);
```

My BroadcastReceiver (NotifcationReceiver)

```
  [BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.attendbehavior.attendpc.NotifcationReceiver", Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class NotifcationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
           // If the app is in foreground show an alert
           // Else send a local notification.
        }
    }
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="101" android:versionName="1.01" package="com.attendbehavior.attendpc" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.attendbehavior.attendpc.NotifcationReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**NOTE**  I tried adding combinations of these on my receiver and they seem to make what I have working stop working.

```
    android:process=":remote"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
```

Comment: Hi, if app is not running (ie not in Foreground / Background), local notification can not be invoked. You could use [Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) to show local notification even the app is not running.

Comment: Thanks.  Did really come to the same conclusion.  Ended up with using server based notifications (Firebase).  Not ideal (offline support), but much cleaner.

Comment: Okey, if have solved that, you could update it as an asnwer. Then others who have the same problem will know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the conclusion that I came to.  Hopefully it will help others.

1. I could not get local notifications to work with the app killed and no foreground service.
2. A foreground service works fine, but is really annoying to end users. (I.M.O.)
3. Server notifications (Firebase) was the way I ended up going.

Comment: Hi, gald you have updated it as the answer. In addittion, remember to mark it when you have time, it also will be helpful for others who meet the same problem.